# When pausing an XNA Xbox game and showing a "pause menu", which controller buttons should I use?

Tags: game-design, xbox360, xbox-controller

I'm making a simple 2D XNA game for Xbox 360. My game can be paused by pressing the `Start` button on the Xbox controller. While paused, a simple menu pops up with options like `Resume` and `Exit to Title Screen`. The way I've currently programmed it, the menu options can only be selected with the `A` button on the Xbox controller, but I've found that I intuitively want to press `Start` to resume the action again.

I think it's a given that `Start` pauses the game and displays the pause menu, but once the pause menu is displayed, I can think of 3 options for dealing with input:

- Menu options can be selected with the `A` button. `Start` does nothing.
- Menu options can be selected with the `A` button or the `Start` button.
- Menu options can be selected with the `A` button. `Start` resumes gameplay regardless of which menu option is selected.

What's the best control scheme to pause a game and accept input on a pause screen menu? Are there any guidelines or standards to help choose between these options?

Comment: Microsoft requires the following in XBLA games and should be put in place in an indie game, I know it doesn't answer the question but I thought you might want to know it.

> Resume Game 
>Help & Options [submenu]
>> How to Play
>> Controls  
>> Settings  
>> Credits (if applicable)
>Leaderboards  (not required on indie game)
>Achievements (not applicable on indie game)
>Save Game (if applicable)
>Exit Game

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a gamer, I appreciate it when games use the following conventions:

- I press Start to pause the game.
- Unless it has some special function (like bringing up a secondary menu), I want the B button to unpause the game.
- Same goes for Start button.
- I want to move the selection with either the left thumbstick or the D-pad, and I want the selection to wrap. ie: If I am at the top of the list and press up, then it should go to the bottom.
- 'A' button selects menu items.

Also, slightly unrelated, but when the game is paused, keep a timer and if there's no user input after 3-5 seconds or something please fade down the music and other continuously playing sound effects.

**Update**

Adding Trevor's comment in the answer because it's important:

> An extra often-forgotten point: Any current controller vibration should be stopped as soon as the pause screen is opened. The vibration should NOT be resumed when leaving the pause screen.

Comment: An extra often-forgotten point:  Any current controller vibration should be stopped as soon as the pause screen is opened.  The vibration should NOT be resumed when leaving the pause screen.  Example:  I'm caught in an explosion, triggering a few seconds of controller vibration.  Before that vibration ends, I pause to go do other things.  When I return and un-pause, I shouldn't feel any controller vibration from the explosion which occurred before the pause screen, but only from the next explosion or other vibration source that I encounter in the game.